# Excel FILTER function not returning expected results for date range: how to filter dates within 6 months of today?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What could be causing the formula

```
=FILTER(MASTER[End Date], AND(MASTER[End Date]>=EDATE(TODAY(),-6), MASTER[End Date]<=TODAY()),"NONE")
```

to not pull any data from the "MASTER" worksheet despite containing dates? The goal of the formula is to filter dates that are within 6 months of today's date to make tracking easier, but it currently returns "NONE". How can this formula be modified to achieve the desired results? My Master worksheet is a query of two worksheets that contain the data.

I tried using this formula:

```
=FILTER(MASTER[End Date], MASTER[End Date]>=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY())-2, DAY(TODAY())), "NONE")
```

However, this formula then returned all the dates in my Master worksheet table. I'm not sure if I'm making things more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a representative sample of dates (as ***text*** which can be copy/pasted) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 4):

[Excel's Filter function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) cannot accept AND conditions as it creates a ***single*** result (i.e. `{false}`) rather than an ARRAY of true/false results (i.e. `{true,false,true}` ). This is not hard to get around by using boolean logic to create the array. Make the conditions multiples of each other and you'll get the desired result. I think yours would be:

```
=FILTER(MASTER[End Date], (MASTER[End Date]>=EDATE(TODAY(),-6))*(MASTER[End Date]<=TODAY()),"NONE")
```

If you need to do an `OR` condition, have the conditions **added** together rather than multiplied. See screenshot below for examples:

(see below for improved method)

[image]

#### Update With Performance Tip

Strangely, with both `AND`/ `OR` formulas, Excel will calculate **ALL** evaluations in a set, even if it has enough information to reach a conclusive result. As an example, if you step through the evaluation of the formula `=AND(1+1=3,5=6,0>9)` you will see the formula reduces all *three* evaluations even though just a single result is enough to conclude the result should be `FALSE`.

Speaking from personal experience, I've seen major performance improvements by changing the conditional methods used for filtering datasets on multiple conditions by using an `if` formula instead of what I posted in my original answer. An `if` formula will discontinue calculations when it's written in a way where no more calls are needed.  Using my previous example, I'd write it as:

`=FILTER(MASTER[End Date], If(MASTER[End Date]>=EDATE(TODAY(),-6),MASTER[End Date]<=TODAY(),FALSE),"NONE")`

For best results, put the calculation that will most likely return a final result FIRST, to avoid having to do a second calc.