# How to alter an ArrayFormula to accommodate for OR functions?

Tags: google-sheets

I have this system that essentially checks whether Heat Acclimatization is maintained. The current situation is, that as long as there are at least 2 activities every other week starting from the week they got acclimatized then it is good to go. And the code below checks 2 weeks by 2 weeks.

Now I want to change it so that every week they will need at least 1 activity and they can put an "E" for "Exemption" in the "Week #" column if they need to break the 1 activity per week rule. But no matter how I alter the code it just gives back true.

[image: Current Code]

I tried adding OR functions to accommodate more conditions but every time I have an OR function in the innermost IF function it will always come out as "Y" which is wrong. I am not sure whether it is because of the OR or maybe I am doing something wrong with the COUNTIF that it is not moving with the OFFSET function.

[image: What I tried]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an `OR` function for an array formula. It's going to create a single result when you want an array of results. Since you didn't include your example as text, I can't copy paste a similar example but consider something like replacing a formula like this... `if(Or(A3>B3,.C3>D3),2,4)` with `If(A3>B3,2,if(C3>D3,2,4))`.

This would also work, but it lacks the advantage compared to the `if` function as it will continue calculations even after a `true` value is achieved: `((A3>B3)+(C3>D3))`

One could argue there's NEVER a good reason to use an `OR` function as it only simplifies the formula to the human, but is not efficient as far as processing in that the `OR` function will not halt the calculation if a `true` despite future calculations no longer being necessary. An `iF` statement will not execute calculations for conditions that have evaluated to not be needed in a calc (i.e. in first example `If(A3>B3,` is true, then that ends the calcs.

[See similar discussion on this with the And function.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75944184/excel-filter-function-not-returning-expected-results-for-date-range-how-to-filt/75945402#75945402)